# Unlink() not working

Tags: php, file-io, unlink

I am trying to delete a file from the Server.

The files of my application is in a folder name "/public_html/app/";

All the images associated with the application is located in the following path: "/public_html/app/images/tryimg/"

The file in which I am writing the below code spec is in "/public_html/app/".

Here is my code snipet:

```
<?php

$m_img = "try.jpg"

$m_img_path = "images/tryimg".$m_img;

if (file_exists($m_img_path))
{
     unlink($m_img_path);
}
// See if it exists again to be sure it was removed
if (file_exists($m_img))
{
          echo "Problem deleting " . $m_img_path;
}
else
{
        echo "Successfully deleted " . $m_img_path;
}
?>
```

When the above script is executed the message "Successfully deleted try.jpg" is displayed.

But when I navigate to the folder, the file is not deleted.

Apache: 2.2.17
PHP version: 5.3.5

What am I doing wrong?

Do I have to give a relative or absolute path to the image?

Comment: You are calling `unlink()` with `$m_img_path`, but `file_exists()` with `$m_img`.

Comment: Besides the wrong path, you should consider to call `clearstatcache()` to avoid wrong results of the second `file_exist()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're missing a directory separator:

```
$m_img = "try.jpg"

$m_img_path = "images/tryimg".$m_img;

// You end up with this..
$m_img_path == 'images/tryimgtry.jpg';
```

You need to add a slash:

```
$m_img_path = "images/tryimg". DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $m_img;
```

You also need to change your second file_exists call as you're using the image name and not the path:

```
if (file_exists($m_img_path))
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your help. I changed the second file_exists with image_path. But it is still not working

Comment: Hi Andrew, the path was wrong it the code...  Thanks for your help much appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You check the wrong path:

```
if (file_exists($m_img))
```

while you (tried to) delete(d) `$m_img_path`, so replace your check with

```
if (file_exists($m_img_path))
```

[`unlink()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) returns a boolean value to indicate whether the deletion succeeded or not, so it is easier/better to use this value:

```
if (file_exists($m_img_path)) 
{
    if(unlink($m_img_path))
    {
        echo "Successfully deleted " . $m_img_path;
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Problem deleting " . $m_img_path;
    }
}
```

Furthermore, the current directory is at the location where the script is executed, so you need to keep this in mind when using a relative path. In most situations it is probably better/easier to use absolute paths if possible.

If you need paths to a lot of files on your server, you might want to put the absolute path in a variable and use that, so it is easy to change the absolute location if your server configuration changes.

Comment: Hi Veger, Thank for the help. When I am using the code you have provided, no message is displayed. I am lost....

Comment: That is because the file specified by `$m_img_path` probably does not exist (or cannot be found because your relative/absolute path is incorrect). Try to echo the value of this variable and manually check if it is incorrect, [Andrew noted already that you are missing a directory separator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021390/unlink-not-working/15021696#15021696), so at least add that one!

Comment: Hi Veger, the path was wrong it the code.... I have also added the missing directory separator indicated by Andrew.... Thanks for your help much appreciate it